# notification via service starts randomly

Tags: android

I try to make simple reminder with notification via service. I choose time of some action and I want to set notification 10min before finish of that time. It's work once, i set timer to 12min and I have notification after 2min. But then i get random notification every 25-35min
Ofcourse i can have few notifications at once and they works, but then i get that random notifications and i dont know how to stop them... Should I send notification id to service and stop service after send notification?

Code of timer:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Review.this, AlarmService.class);

            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Review.this, unique,     intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)     getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currTimestamp - (10 * 60000), pintent);
```

and code of service:

```
 notifyMgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
Notification notifyObj=new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "alarm",     System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainList.class),  0);
notifyObj.setLatestEventInfo(this, "10 min to finish", "Click here to see list", i);
notifyObj.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; 
notifyObj.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notifyObj.flags|=Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;    
notifyMgr.notify(1, notifyObj);
```

I try Flags: one shot and only alert once but still I get this random notifications :/
Maybe whole code is just wrong... no idea